# Java - UIManager.setLookAndFeel isn't working

Tags: java, swing, awt, look-and-feel, uimanager

I'm trying to get look and feel to work with no success. I'm creating a Frame and painting an Applet inside it. No exceptions are thrown when I execute the program.

AppScreen < Applet:

```
public class AppScreen extends Applet implements Runnable {

    protected AppFrame frame;
    protected Graphics appGraphics;

    public void createFrame(int width, int height) throws Exception {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("org.jvnet.substance.skin.SubstanceRavenGraphiteGlassLookAndFeel");
        frame = new AppFrame(this, width, height);
        appGraphics = getAppComponent().getGraphics();
        startThread(this, 1);
    }

    public void startThread(Runnable runnable, int i) {
        final Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
        thread.setPriority(i);
    }

    public Component getAppComponent() {
        if (frame != null)
            return frame;
        else
            return this;
    }
}
```

AppFrame < Frame:

```
public final class AppFrame extends Frame {

    private final AppScreen screen;

    public AppFrame(AppScreen screen, int width, int height) {
        this.screen = screen;
        setBounds(500, 500, width, height);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
        toFront();
    }

    @Override
    public final void update(Graphics g) {
        screen.update(g);
    }

    @Override
    public final void paint(Graphics g) {
        screen.paint(g);
    }

}
```

For instance, I call createFrame(width, height) method.

Comment: L&F is Swing concept and pertains only to Swing components. java.awt.Applet and java.awt.Frame are not Swing components and will always be rendered using native UI system.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin Is there a way I can use to get around it. Like creating a javax.swing.JFrame and painting the applet inside it?

Comment: Use Swing components instead of AWT(`Applet`->`JApplet`, `Frame`->`JFrame`...)

Comment: @alex2410 should be an answer because AWT haven't access to L&F, is strictly based on peers from Native OS

Comment: Use Swing components as said by others and set L&F in your main method before creating any component.

Comment: *"I'm creating a Frame and painting an Applet inside it."*  That is a horrid way to go about things.  Code the GUI as a `JPanel` that can be added to a frame or applet (then avoid applets like the plague).